# Style is not binding in css

Tags: css

i am trying to bind style in my css style using below format but its not working and i am learner for web development can some one help me please what is mistack?

### css

```
.block-header.row.sample h1{
        color: aqua;
    }
```

### html

```
 <div class="block-header">
        <div class="row sample">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="page-title">Pending Approvals</h1>
          </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Two selectors  without a space between them (`.a.b`) applies to elements that satisfy *both*. A space between selectors (`.a .b`) means *"descendant of"*.

Answer (score 0):

Your style rule is wrong, it should be: `.block-header .row.sample h1` instead of `.block-header.row.sample h1`. When you have a style for an element that's a descendant of another one (in your case `.row.sample` is a child of `.block-header`) you should have the parent first, followed by a space (or `>` if it's a direct child) and then the descendant element, just like you're doing with the `h1`...

You can see it works with that simple change:

```css
.block-header .row.sample h1{
        color: aqua;
}
```

```html
 <div class="block-header">
        <div class="row sample">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="page-title">Pending Approvals</h1>
          </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

You can read more about [selectors in mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your rule is that there are no spaces between your classes, which makes the selector *any h1 element with the parent having classes block-header, row, and sample*.

You would need to put spaces so that the selector knows these elements are nested inside each other:

```
.block-header .row.sample h1 {
    color: aqua;
}
```

Learn more about how these selectors work from [this FreeCodeCamp guide](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/css/tutorials/css-selectors-cheat-sheet/).